# How to render Bing Map tiles at lower resolution for zooms greater than max on Openlayers

Tags: bing-maps, openlayers-3

I have an openlayers3 map that loads Aerial tiles from Bing Maps.

When the zoom exceeds a certain amount, the tiles are replaced by a white tile with a no imagery icon.

[image]

I need to allow the user to zoom beyond this level so they can see the position of vector features on the map.

I would like to have openlayers or Bing zoom into the existing image, even though the resolution will not be good, it is better than the white tile.

The closest information I could find is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26077167/2023941) to another question by user:457052. It may apply to openlayers2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set maxZoom in ol.source.BingMaps  By default it will be set to the maximum level where there is data in some part of the world.  Find the maximum level that works in your region (for UK it's 19) and limit it to that.

Comment: Thanks. I was surprised this works because my ol.source.BingMaps docs don't mention you can apply maxZoom, or that it works to zoom the tiles. Its new to BingMaps V8.
Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/16300412/2023941 shows how to use map.getTargetZoom() to dynamically get the maxZoom for a given view or region.

Comment: Yes, it would help it OL explained what it for in the main documentation, the only useful mention you will find is in one of the examples http://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/bing-maps.html